# Zero under diagonal elements by given column index

Tags: matlab

Having square matrix `A` and I want to zero all its under diagonal elements in column `i` using operations performed on the associated matrix as describe in [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) ,

mean `R(t) = R(t)-m*R(i)  | t > i` .

I tried `A( (i+1):n,: ) = A( (i+1):n,: ) - (A( (i+1):n)/A(i,i))*(A(i,:))` with no luck .

you can assume that `i` isn't the last column .

**Edit:**

For example  - for `i=1` the follow matrix `A`

[image]

become to be -

[image]

since `m=1/4` and `m=2/4` for 2nd 3nd row respectively   .

Comment: Show examples. As is your question is vague

Comment: What do you mean by a quadratic matrix? Never seen one of them.

Comment: @woodchips : sorry ..  English isn't my native and I relied on google translate . fixed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would solve your problem is through basic linear algebra...

First divide the residual row by the diagonal element, multiply the row vector to the main column vector to be removed (resulting in a n*m matrix) then subtract from the submatrix to be operated on:

```
A(i+1:end,i:end) = A(i+1:end,i:end)- A(i+1:end,i)* A(i,i:end)/A(i,i)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the product, which you would like to be a mix between the matricial product and the component-wise product.

Here is one way to get rid of the problem (maybe not the nicest way):

```
A( (i+1):n,: ) = A( (i+1):n,: ) -  ((A( (i+1):n,:  )/A(i,i)).*( ones(n-i,1) *(A(i,:))))
```

The additional multiplication by the vector of `1` create a matrix whose size is the same as `A( (i+1):n)` but with `A(i,:)` in each line. The component-wise product can then be used. This gives the correct answer without explicit loop.